# My App always show "Hello World"

Tags: android, andengine

Hi I'm new in Android Developing.

I want to create an easy game using AndEngine. So I wanted to try a little sample. But when i deploy the apk-file to my nexus7. But when I run the App, it always says "Hello World" in the center of screen with White Background. But it should show an Image with specific Background Color.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
private static final float CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final float CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private Camera mCamera;
private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private Engine mEngine;
private TextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                    CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {

    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
            mEngine.getTextureManager(), 32, 32,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this,
                    "face_box.png", 0, 0);

    getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas);
}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new Background(new Color(0, 255, 128)));
    final int centerX = (int) ((CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion
            .getWidth()) / 2);
    final int centerY = (int) ((CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion
            .getHeight()) / 2);
    final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY,
            this.mFaceTextureRegion, new VertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(face);

    return scene;
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try doing a text search for Hello World.

Comment: Mind showing `activity_main.xml`? I'd bet it includes something akin to `@string/hello_world`.

Comment: thanks for your answers. You're right Eric. I have a activity_main.xml which Shows the "hello world" and a MainActivity.java. What do i have to do, to Show MainActivity.java instead of activity_main.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using AndEngine SimpleBaseGameActivity, you don't need this

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

"Hello world" shows up because you are setting the content view, remove the override to onCreate and it should work.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Before I used "BaseGameActivity".

Comment: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/what-is-the-order-of-the-engine-t6785.html
Here's a link explaining the difference between the several *GameActivity in AndEngine (I had a tough time sorting this out when I started using AndEngine)

Comment: Removing either of those lines gives me an `Unfortunately app has stopped` error

Comment: @MatthewDrill Hey, this answer is from a long time ago. I can't recommend AndEngine now, but what GameActivity class are you inheriting from?